# How to instantiate an array of struct inside a struct

Tags: solidity

```
Collection[] public collections;

struct Book {
    string name;
    address writer;
    bytes32 proof;
}

struct Collection {
    Book[] books;
    address collectionCreator;
}

// Question: how to push a new collection?
function newCollection() public {
    collections.append(Collection({
        collectionCreator: msg.sender,
        // ISSUE HERE
        books: <HELP>
    }))
}
```

How to instantiate this new array of a struct inside a struct?

Comment: In all honesty, this seems really confusing to implement, you could look at using alternatives, like using a mapping instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest thing to do is as follows:

```
function newCollection() public {
    // Increase the array length first
    collections.length += 1;

    // Get a reference to the new element
    Collection storage collection = collections[collections.length - 1];

    // Set its members as needed        
    collection.collectionCreator = msg.sender;
    // collection.books.push(...);
}
```